# Is it faster in MySQL to have one filter or several for the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

In MySQL, I always consider:

`.... WHERE type > 5`

to be faster than:

`... WHERE type != 4 AND type != 6 AND type != 10`

That is, I believe it is faster to one 'larger than' or 'smaller   than' statement than having several comparison (equal to's or not equal to's). However, I have absolutely no idea if this is a valid thought. Anybody any idea?

Comment: Have you checked the explain plan on a sufficiently large enough table (IE: 1+ million rows)?  And what about indexing...  I personally would not want to use the latter approach for sake of all the typing...

Comment: one comparison instead of many improves readability & maintainability, regardless of efficiency

Comment: I did some very simple testing and in this case the single > was faster than the several != comparisons. But I do not my very non-scientific test too much. Also, the dbase had some 100,000 records...

Comment: @yitwail Agreed, but two or three comparisons are still not too complicated and if I am not losing out on efficiency I'd not restructure things (which I perhaps would do if I would have to sacrifice efficiency)

Comment: They are testing different things, so I'm not sure why you are trying to compare them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is virtually the same, as long as you don't have 1000 conditions in the WHERE clause. When trying to optimize sql queries, focus more on the multi-table operations, joins etc. This is a minor thing. Don't focus on this too much. If you try too much to optimize you can complicate your database and code with almost no benefit.

Once I was in a situation when it was better to have a multiple conditions OR'ed in the WHERE clause than join another table - using multiple WHERE condition was much more efficient because I saved one join.

Comment: agree, but style-wise, fewer comparisons is better

Comment: I think the same, but perhaps one of them _is_ faster and if I can structure the query for either options I'd like to know what would have a (albeit tiny) speed benefit.

Comment: I'd advice you, don't focus on that much. If you try too much to optimize you can complicate your database and code with almost no benefit. Also, once I was in a case that it was better to have a multiple conditions OR'ed in the WHERE clause because there was no need to join another table! It was much more efficient.